# Подскажите в файловой системе сайта на хостинге в какой папке можно найти, какая база данных подвязана к сайту?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, база-данных

Подскажите в файловой системе сайта на хостинге в какой папке можно найти, какая база данных подвязана к сайту? Скриншот файловой системы прилагаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: wp-config посмотрите нам все настройки вордпресса, думаю соединение с БД там же

Comment: @Mike в ответ это напиши.

Answer (score 1):

У вас на скриншоте в файловой системе есть файл – wp-config.php. Обычно именно в нем хранятся настройки подключения к базе данных: сервер, имя БД, имя пользователя, пароль.
Смотрите вот эту часть файла:

```
/** Имя базы данных для WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');

/** Имя пользователя MySQL */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');

/** Пароль к базе данных MySQL */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');

/** Имя сервера MySQL */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```